# Best approach for designing F# libraries for use from both F# and C#

Tags: c#, f#

I am trying to design a library in F#. The library should be friendly for use from *both F# and C#*.

And this is where I'm stuck a little bit.  I can make it F# friendly, or I can make it C# friendly, but the problem is how to make it friendly for both.

Here is an example.  Imagine I have the following function in F#:

```ml
let compose (f: 'T -> 'TResult) (a : 'TResult -> unit) = f >> a
```

This is perfectly usable from F#:

```ml
let useComposeInFsharp() =
    let composite = compose (fun item -> item.ToString) (fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
    composite "foo"
    composite "bar"
```

In C#, the `compose` function has the following signature:

```cs
FSharpFunc<T, Unit> compose<T, TResult>(FSharpFunc<T, TResult> f, FSharpFunc<TResult, Unit> a);
```

But of course, I don't want `FSharpFunc` in the signature, what I want is `Func` and `Action` instead, like this:

```cs
Action<T> compose2<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> f, Action<TResult> a);
```

To achieve this, I can create `compose2` function like this:

```ml
let compose2 (f: Func<'T, 'TResult>) (a : Action<'TResult> ) = 
    new Action<'T>(f.Invoke >> a.Invoke)
```

Now, this is perfectly usable in C#:

```cs
void UseCompose2FromCs()
{
    compose2((string s) => s.ToUpper(), Console.WriteLine);
}
```

But now we have a problem using `compose2` from F#!  Now I have to wrap all standard F# `funs` into `Func` and `Action`, like this:

```ml
let useCompose2InFsharp() =
    let f = Func<_,_>(fun item -> item.ToString())
    let a = Action<_>(fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
    let composite2 = compose2 f a

    composite2.Invoke "foo"
    composite2.Invoke "bar"
```

**The question:** How can we achieve first-class experience for the library written in F# for both F# and C# users?

So far, I couldn't come up with anything better than these two approaches:

1. Two separate assemblies: one targeted to F# users, and the second to C# users.
2. One assembly but different namespaces: one for F# users, and the second for C# users.

For the first approach, I would do something like this:

1. Create a F# project, call it FooBarFs and compile it into FooBarFs.dll.

   - Target the library purely to F# users.
   - Hide everything unnecessary from the .fsi files.
2. Create another F# project, call if FooBarCs and compile it into FooFar.dll

   - Reuse the first F# project at the source level.
   - Create .fsi file which hides everything from that project.
   - Create .fsi file which exposes the library in C# way, using C# idioms for name, namespaces, etc.
   - Create wrappers that delegate to the core library, doing the conversion where necessary.

I think the second approach with the namespaces can be confusing to the users, but then you have one assembly.

**The question:** None of these are ideal, perhaps I am missing some kind of compiler flag/switch/attribute
or some kind of trick and there is a better way of doing this?

**The question:** has anyone else tried to achieve something similar and if so how did you do it?

EDIT: to clarify, the question is not only about functions and delegates but the overall experience of a C# user with an F# library. This includes namespaces, naming conventions, idioms and suchlike that are native to C#. Basically, a C# user shouldn't be able to detect that the library was authored in F#. And vice versa, an F# user should feel like dealing with a C# library.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I can see from the answers and comments so far that my question lacks the necessary depth,
perhaps mostly due to use of only one example where interoperability issues between F# and C# 
arise, the issue of function values.  I think this is the most obvious example and so this
led me to use it to ask the question, but by the same token gave the impression that this is
the only issue I am concerned with.

Let me provide more concrete examples. I have read through the most excellent
[F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/)
document (many thanks @gradbot for this!). The guidelines in the document, if used, do address
some of the issues but not all.

The document is split into two main parts: 1) guidelines for targeting F# users; and 2) guidelines for
targeting C# users.  Nowhere does it even attempt to pretend that it is possible to have a uniform
approach, which exactly echoes my question: we can target F#, we can target C#, but what is the
practical solution for targeting both?

To remind, the goal is to have a library authored in F#, and which can be used *idiomatically* from
both F# and C# languages.

The keyword here is *idiomatic*. The issue is not the general interoperability where it is just possible
to use libraries in different languages.

Now to the examples, which I take straight from 
[F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/).

1. Modules+functions (F#) vs Namespaces+Types+functions

   - F#: Do use namespaces or modules to contain your types and modules.
     The idiomatic use is to place functions in modules, e.g.:

     ```
     // library
     module Foo
     let bar() = ...
     let zoo() = ...


     // Use from F#
     open Foo
     bar()
     zoo()
     ```
   - C#: Do use namespaces, types and members as the primary organizational structure for your 
     components (as opposed to modules), for vanilla .NET APIs.

     This is incompatible with the F# guideline, and the example would need
     to be re-written to fit the C# users:

     ```
     [<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
     type Foo =
         static member bar() = ...
         static member zoo() = ...
     ```

     By doing so though, we break the idiomatic use from F# because
     we can no longer use `bar` and `zoo` without prefixing it with `Foo`.
2. Use of tuples

   - F#: Do use tuples when appropriate for return values.
   - C#: Avoid using tuples as return values in vanilla .NET APIs.
3. Async

   - F#: Do use Async for async programming at F# API boundaries.
   - C#: Do expose asynchronous operations using either the .NET asynchronous programming model 
     (BeginFoo, EndFoo), or as methods returning .NET tasks (Task), rather than as F# Async 
     objects.
4. Use of `Option`

   - F#: Consider using option values for return types instead of raising exceptions (for F#-facing code).
   - Consider using the TryGetValue pattern instead of returning F# option values (option) in vanilla 
     .NET APIs, and prefer method overloading over taking F# option values as arguments.
5. Discriminated unions

   - F#: Do use discriminated unions as an alternative to class hierarchies for creating tree-structured data
   - C#: *no specific guidelines for this, but the concept of discriminated unions is foreign to C#*
6. Curried functions

   - F#: *curried functions are idiomatic for F#*
   - C#: Do not use currying of parameters in vanilla .NET APIs.
7. Checking for null values

   - F#: *this is not idiomatic for F#*
   - C#: Consider checking for null values on vanilla .NET API boundaries.
8. Use of F# types `list`, `map`, `set`, etc

   - F#: *it is idiomatic to use these in F#*
   - C#: Consider using the .NET collection interface types IEnumerable and IDictionary
     for parameters and return values in vanilla .NET APIs. (*i.e. do not use F# `list`, `map`, `set`*)
9. Function types (the obvious one)

   - F#: *use of F# functions as values is idiomatic for F#, obviously*
   - C#: Do use .NET delegate types in preference to F# function types in vanilla .NET APIs.

I think these should be sufficient to demonstrate the nature of my question.

Incidentally, the guidelines also have a partial answer:

> ... a common implementation strategy when developing higher-order 
>   methods for vanilla .NET libraries is to author all the implementation using F# function types, and 
>   then create the public API using delegates as a thin façade atop the actual F# implementation.

**To summarise.**

There is one definite answer: *there are no compiler tricks that I missed*.

As per the guidelines doc, it seems that authoring for F# first and then creating
a facade wrapper for .NET is a reasonable strategy.

The question then remains regarding the practical implementation of this:

- Separate assemblies? or
- Different namespaces?

If my interpretation is correct, Tomas suggests that using separate namespaces should
be sufficient, and should be an acceptable solution.

I think I will agree with that given that the choice of namespaces is such that it
does not surprise or confuse the .NET/C# users, which means that the namespace
for them should probably look like it is the primary namespace for them.  The
F# users will have to take the burden of choosing F#-specific namespace.
For example:

- FSharp.Foo.Bar  -> namespace for F# facing the library
- Foo.Bar         -> namespace for .NET wrapper, idiomatic for C#

Comment: Somewhat relevant http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf

Comment: Other than passing around first-class functions, what are your concerns? F# already goes a long way toward providing a seamless experience from other languages.

Comment: Re: your edit, I'm still unclear as to why you think a library authored in F# would appear non-standard from C#. For the most part, F# provides a superset of C# functionality. Making a library feel natural is mostly a matter of convention, which is true no matter what language you're using. All that to say, F# provides all the tools you need to do this.

Comment: Honestly even though you include a code sample, you're asking a fairly open-ended question.  You ask about "the overall experience of a C# user with an F# library" but the only example you give is something that really isn't supported well in _any_ imperative language.  Treating functions as first class citizens is a pretty central tenet of functional programming--which maps poorly to most imperative languages.

Comment: @gradbot I think your comment really deserved to be an answer

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I have supplied a variety of examples beyond functions, please see EDIT 2.

Comment: @Daniel please see EDIT 2, I hope it clarifies the clarification :)

Comment: @KomradeP.: regarding your EDIT 2, [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) provides some means to make interoperability more seemless. You could find some hints in [this excellent blog post](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/10/10-reasons-to-use-f-runtime-in-your-c.html).

Comment: @KomradeP.: I edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: [FsCheck](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck) like **fs** states in the name, it's more **F#** oriented, but I think could be a good example. I would design everything in functional way and then add a thin OO layer for other .NET languages (taking care most of all of **C#** and **VB.NET**). To be completely friendly to all .NET languages, for me the best option is always **C#**.

Comment: [QuoteFs](https://github.com/gsscoder/quote.fs) is mine (at moment of writing limited) experiment.

Answer (score 41):

Daniel already explained how to define a C#-friendly version of the F# function that you wrote, so I'll add some higher-level comments. First of all, you should read the [F# Component Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines) (referenced already by gradbot). This is a document that explains how to design F# and .NET libraries using F# and it should answer many of your questions.

When using F#, there are basically two kinds of libraries you can write:

- **F# library** is designed to be used *only* from F#, so it's public interface is written in a functional style (using F# function types, tuples, discriminated unions etc.)
- **.NET library** is designed to be used from *any* .NET language (including C# and F#) and it typically follows .NET object-oriented style. This means that you'll expose most of the functionality as classes with method (and sometimes extension methods or static methods, but mostly the code should be written in the OO design).

In your question, you're asking how to expose function composition as a .NET library, but I think that functions like your `compose` are too low level concepts from the .NET library point of view. You can expose them as methods working with `Func` and `Action`, but that probably isn't how you would design a normal .NET library in the first place (perhaps you'd use the Builder pattern instead or something like that).

In some cases (i.e. when designing numerical libraries that do not really fit well with the .NET library style), it makes a good sense to design a library that mixes both **F#** and **.NET** styles in a single library. The best way to do this is to have normal F# (or normal .NET) API and then provide wrappers for natural use in the other style. The wrappers can be in a separate namespace (like `MyLibrary.FSharp` and `MyLibrary`).

In your example, you could leave the F# implementation in `MyLibrary.FSharp` and then add .NET (C#-friendly) wrappers (similar to code that Daniel posted) in the `MyLibrary` namespace as static method of some class. But again, .NET library would probably have more specific API than function composition.

Comment: The F# Component Design Guidelines are now hosted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines)

Answer (score 19):

You only have to wrap function *values* (partially-applied functions, etc) with `Func` or `Action`, the rest are converted automatically. For example:

```ml
type A(arg) =
  member x.Invoke(f: Func<_,_>) = f.Invoke(arg)

let a = A(1)
a.Invoke(fun i -> i + 1)
```

So it makes sense to use `Func`/`Action` where applicable. Does this eliminate your concerns? I think your proposed solutions are overly-complicated. You can write your entire library in F# and use it pain-free from F# *and* C# (I do it all the time).

Also, F# is more flexible than C# in terms of interoperability so it's generally best to follow traditional .NET style when this is a concern.

EDIT

The work required to make two public interfaces in separate namespaces, I think, is only warranted when they are complementary or the F# functionality is not usable from C# (such as inlined functions, which depend on F#-specific metadata).

Taking your points in turn:

1. Module + `let` bindings and constructor-less type + static members appear exactly the same in C#, so go with modules if you can. You can use [`CompiledNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340493.aspx) to give members C#-friendly names.
2. I may be wrong, but my guess is that the Component Guidelines were written prior to `System.Tuple` being added to the framework. (In earlier versions F# defined it's own tuple type.) It's since become more acceptable to use `Tuple` in a public interface for trivial types.
3. This is where I think you have do things the C# way because F# plays well with `Task` but C# doesn't play well with `Async`. You can use async internally then call [`Async.StartAsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821132.aspx) before returning from a public method.
4. Embrace of `null` may be the single biggest drawback when developing an API for use from C#. In the past, I tried all kinds of tricks to avoid considering null in internal F# code but, in the end, it was best to mark types with public constructors with `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` and check args for null. It's no worse than C# in this respect.
5. Discriminated unions are generally compiled to class hierarchies but always have a relatively friendly representation in C#. I would say, mark them with `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` and use them.
6. Curried functions produce function *values*, which shouldn't be used.
7. I found it was better to embrace null than to depend on it being caught at the public interface and ignore it internally. YMMV.
8. It makes a lot of sense to use `list`/`map`/`set` internally. They can all be exposed through the public interface as `IEnumerable<_>`. Also, [`seq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353788.aspx), [`dict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx), and [`Seq.readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340408.aspx) are frequently useful.
9. See #6.

Which strategy you take depends on the type and size of your library but, in my experience, finding the sweet spot between F# and C# required less work—in the long run—than creating separate APIs.

Comment: yes I can see there are some ways to make things work, I am not entirely convinced. Re modules. If you have `module Foo.Bar.Zoo` then in C# this will be `class Foo` in namespace `Foo.Bar`. However if you have nested modules like `module Foo=... module Bar=... module Zoo==`, this will generate class `Foo` with inner classes `Bar` and `Zoo`.  Re `IEnumerable`, this may not be acceptable when we really need to work with maps and sets. Re `null` values and `AllowNullLiteral` -- one reason I like F# is because I'm tired of `null` in C#, really wouldn't want to pollute everything with it again!

Comment: Generally favor namespaces over nested modules for interop. Re: null, I agree with you, it's certainly a regression to have to consider it, but something you have to deal with if your API will be used from C#.

Answer (score 2):

[Draft F# Component Design Guidelines
(August 2010)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf)

> **Overview**   This document looks at some of the issues related to F# component design and coding. In particular, it  covers:
>
> - Guidelines for designing “vanilla” .NET libraries for use from any .NET language.
> - Guidelines for F#-to-F# libraries and F# implementation code.
> - Suggestions on coding conventions for F# implementation code

Answer (score 2):

Although it probably would be an overkill, you could consider writing an application using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) (it has awesome support on the mailing list) that would automate the conversion on the IL level. For example, you implement your assembly in F#, using the F#-style public API, then the tool would generate a C#-friendly wrapper over it.

For instance, in F# you would obviously use `option<'T>` (`None`, specifically) instead of using `null` like in C#. Writing a wrapper generator for this scenario should be fairly easy: the wrapper method would invoke the original method: if it's return value was `Some x`, then return `x`, otherwise return `null`.

You would need to handle the case when `T` is a value type, i.e. non-nullable; you would have to wrap the return value of the wrapper method into `Nullable<T>`, which makes it a bit painful.

Again, I'm quite certain that it would pay off to write such a tool in your scenario, maybe except if you'll be working on this such library (usable seamlessly from F# and C# both) regularly. In any case, I think it would be an interesting experiment, one that I might even explore sometime.

Comment: sounds interesting. Would using `Mono.Cecil` mean basically writing a program to load F# assembly, find items requiring mapping, and them emitting another assembly with the C# wrappers? Did I get this right?

Comment: @Komrade P.: You can do that too, but that's a lot more complicated, because then you'd have to adjust all the references to point to the members of the new assembly. It's much simpler if you just add the new members (the wrappers) to the existing F#-written assembly.