# How to expose the type as friendly as possible to both C# and F#?

Tags: f#

For example, if I have written a module in F#

```
module Lib

type A =
    member this.x1 x = ...

let helpa x = ...
let helpb x = ...

type B =
    member this.y1 x = ...

let helpc x = ...

typeA with
    member this.x2 x = ...
typeB with
    member this.y2 x = ...
```

It works well in F# by `open Lib`, However, if I want to consume it in C# (where I am only interested in types and member functions in `Lib`), each time I create a type I have to `new Lib.A(...)`.  It becomes rather annoying there is no way to omit the module names. Calling a static method like `Lib.A.C()` is even more of a hassle.

Then I try to replace `module` with `namespace`, each time I introduce some helper functions I have to create a new module with a new name. Occasionally I can manage to rearrange all helper functions into 1 module, but that would result in less readable code somehow.

What would be a better structure for this?

Wish I had: `Using * = Lib.*` for C#.

Comment: Do you have a `using Lib` directive at the top of your C# class?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think C# can `using` module, or do u mean alias such as `using A = Lib.A`?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/478531

Comment: You can find other helpful advices here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110174/best-approach-for-designing-f-libraries-for-use-from-both-f-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already mentioned the best option in your answer - define the file with `namespace` declaration at the top (this way, you can write just `using Lib` in C#) and then place all helper functions in modules.

Helper functions that are clearly associated with some type (e.g. with `A`) could be placed into a module named `A` (similarly to F# functions in the `List` module that are associated with the `List<'T>` type).

This is a bit more work, because you need to mark the module with a special attribute (to avoid name clash), but it will be easy to use from both F# and C# (and I think having nice use is more important than saving a few keystrokes when building the library):

```
namespace Lib

// Declaration of the 'A' type and helper functions in 'A' module 
type A() =
  member this.x1 x = 10

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module A = 
  let helpa (x:A) = x.x1
  let helpb (x:A) = x.x1

// Declaration of the 'B' type and helper functions in 'B' module 
type B() =
  member this.y1 x = 10

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module B = 
  let helpc (x:B) = x.y1

// Member augmentations for easy use from C#
type A with
    member this.x2 x = A.helpa this
type B with
    member this.y2 x = B.helpc this
```

Comment: In C#, A.helpa becomes AModule.helpa.  I have to add the functions as static members of type A.

Answer (score 7):

F# offers more flexibility than C# here, so I would expose it to C# in the standard way, i.e., enclose types in a namespace. Something like this, I think, offers the best of both worlds:

```
namespace Lib

type A =
    member this.x1 x = ()

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module A =
  let helpa x = ()
  let helpb x = ()

type B =
    member this.y1 x = ()

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module B =
  let helpb x = ()

type A with
    member this.x2 x = ()
type B with
    member this.y2 x = ()
```

The F# collections follow a similar design. You can use the `[<AutoOpen>]` and `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attributes to further control how the modules are used from F#.

Comment: daniel, any guidance on how to expose f# types such as unions, record types, in a friendly way to c# ?

Comment: @  l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I have been doing some interop recently and found that f# unions are actually exposed really nicely if you use the new expression based switch syntax like you would use match in f#. Records are just read only classes so very natural anyway.

Comment: An example of what I mentioned above: switch (result)
            {
                case var checkResult when checkResult.IsOk:
                    HandleOk(checkResult.OkValue);
                    break;
                case var checkResult when checkResult.IsError:
                    HandleError(checkResult.ErrorValue);
                    break;
            }

Comment: I just found a great article here: http://connelhooley.uk/blog/2017/04/30/f-sharp-to-c-sharp#cases-with-types

Comment: In addition to my original suggestion for result types, if the union cases have content you can just do switch (unionInstance) { case Union.FirstType content: HandleFirstType(content.Item); break; case Union.SecondType content: HandleSecondType(content.Item); break; }