# Does the "Don't name types the same as namespaces" apply to namespace modules?

Tags: c#, module, f#, namespaces

With regard to [exposing friendly types for multiple consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463631/how-to-expose-the-type-as-friendly-as-possible-to-both-c-sharp-and-f/14463988#14463988) (F#, C#, VB, etc..) Should I apply Eric Lippert's [rule](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx) of not naming types the same as namespaces to modules?

Comment: I suppose I should have specified are there pros/cons to naming a module the same as the enclosing namespace? However, I'd also be interested in hearing about modules the same name as enclosing types if that is different than namespaces owning types

Comment: I would continue to apply the advice with modules.. if they are actually compiled as .NET assembly modules that is. Having not written a lot of code that deals with more than one .NET module in an assembly (C# only has one module per assembly ..) I can't be sure.. but I would guess that you may have similar issues.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead F# modules are compiled as (sealed abstract) classes, not CLR modules.  The compiled CLR class name has "Module" appended.  So, for example, the Seq module in FSharp.Core.dll has the fully-qualified name `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule`

Answer (score 3):

There is a good document describing F# component design guidelines. There is a section there about F# components interfacing with other .NET languages containing naming conventions etc.

http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/