# How can I get the methods defined in a module?

Tags: f#-interactive, fsi

I'm trying to consume an F# assembly from Fsi, but can't seem to find a way to get a list of methods defined in a module so I can call them.

Here's a sample file I'm trying to do this with. In following the ["exposing methods that are cross language friendly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463631/how-to-expose-the-type-as-friendly-as-possible-to-both-c-sharp-and-f/14463988#14463988), I've added a namespace to the top of the file and added a module to contain the let bound methods that were there previously. I'd like to avoid moving everything into static classes if possible.

Can I use reflection, or write the module in another way that helps me find the available methods and proper casing of the methods?

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood the problem, I would proceed as follows:

1) Get the desired assembly. For example, the assembly that is currently being executed can be obtained by

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
```

2) Then I would take all the types defined in the obtained assembly by calling `GetTypes`. If you want to filter out modules you could write something like.

```
let modules = Array.filter (fun x -> FSharpType.IsModule x) (assembly.GetTypes())
```

The documentation for the `FSharpType` class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370530.aspx). It is included in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` namespace.

3) After, you can obtain the methods in a module by calling `GetMethods` method on a single module. For example, to print them all, you could write something like:

```
let methods = [| for t in modules do for m in t.GetMethods() -> m |]
for m in methods do
    printfn "%A" m
```

`methods` is an array containing `MethodInfo` elements. `GetMethods` takes an optional parameter of type [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) that can filter out some methods. Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also invoke actions by calling the `Invoke` method on a `MethodInfo` object.

Hope this was useful.